# Can't do anything with text file contents (file_get_contents)

Tags: php, laravel

**FIXED!**

File encoding is UTF-16LE, changed to UTF-8 in PhpStorm and it behaves.

===========================================================

I'm reading a text file in PHP and want to read and manipulate the contents, but as soon as I touch the read contents of the file in anyway it 'breaks'.

If I read the file then echo it the text is displayed but any other operation with not work.

```
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
echo $contents; // works
$contents .= 'a longer test' . $contents;
echo $contents;
```

My ultimate goal is to run some regex’s on the contents before dumping it into a database but I need to be able to work with it first.

If it makes any difference I am using Laravel. I tried `File::get($file)` but have the same outcome.

EDIT to show output - Unicode issue?

> `//// first echo
>   POUR L ’É T U DE DE L ’H IST O IR E ET DE LA LANGUE DU PAYS, LA CONSERVATION DES A N TIQ U ITÉS DE L ’IL E , ET LA PUBLICATION DE DOCUMENTS HISTORIQUES, ETC., ETC. FONDÉE LE 28 JANVIER, 1873. DIXIÈME BULLETIN ANNUEL. : C. LE F E U VRE, IM PR IM E U R -É D IT EU R D E LA SOCIÉTÉ, BERESFORD LIBRARY , ST. -H ÉLIE R . 1885. = Page 1 =`
>
> `// Second echo
>   POUR L ’É T U DE DE L ’H IST O IR E ET DE LA LANGUE DU PAYS, LA CONSERVATION DES A N TIQ U ITÉS DE L ’IL E , ET LA PUBLICATION DE DOCUMENTS HISTORIQUES, ETC., ETC. FONDÉE LE 28 JANVIER, 1873. DIXIÈME BULLETIN ANNUEL. : C. LE F E U VRE, IM PR IM E U R -É D IT EU R D E LA SOCIÉTÉ, BERESFORD LIBRARY , ST. -H ÉLIE R . 1885. = Page 1 =⁡潬杮牥琠獥ｴ෾਀ഀ਀匀伀䌀䤀䔀吀䔀  䨀䔀刀匀䤀䄀䤀匀䔀ഀ਀倀伀唀刀  䰀 ᤀ줠 吀 唀 䐀䔀  䐀䔀  䰀 ᤀ䠠 䤀匀吀 伀 䤀刀 䔀  䔀吀  䐀䔀  䰀䄀  䰀䄀一䜀唀䔀  䐀唀  倀䄀夀匀Ⰰഀ਀䰀䄀  䌀伀一匀䔀刀嘀䄀吀䤀伀一  䐀䔀匀  䄀 一 吀䤀儀 唀 䤀吀준匀  䐀䔀  䰀 ᤀ䤠䰀 䔀 Ⰰ  䔀吀  䰀䄀  倀唀䈀䰀䤀䌀䄀吀䤀伀一 ഀ਀䐀䔀  䐀伀䌀唀䴀䔀一吀匀  䠀䤀匀吀伀刀䤀儀唀䔀匀Ⰰ  䔀吀䌀⸀Ⰰ  䔀吀䌀⸀ഀ਀䘀伀一䐀준䔀  䰀䔀  ㈀㠀  䨀䄀一嘀䤀䔀刀Ⰰ  ㄀㠀㜀㌀⸀ഀ਀䐀䤀堀䤀저䴀䔀  䈀唀䰀䰀䔀吀䤀一  䄀一一唀䔀䰀⸀ഀ਀㨀ഀ਀䌀⸀  䰀䔀   䘀 䔀 唀 嘀刀䔀Ⰰ  䤀䴀 倀刀 䤀䴀 䔀 唀 刀 ⴀ준 䐀 䤀吀 䔀唀 刀   䐀 䔀  䰀䄀  匀伀䌀䤀준吀준Ⰰഀ਀䈀䔀刀䔀匀䘀伀刀䐀  䰀䤀䈀刀䄀刀夀 Ⰰ  匀吀⸀ ⴀ䠀 준䰀䤀䔀 刀 ⸀ഀ਀㄀㠀㠀㔀⸀਀ഀ 㴀 倀愀最攀 ㄀ 㴀`

If I put the first string into a HEREDOC all works fine, so might be something with the txt file? It's extracted text from an OCRd from am old PDF.

**Full code**

```
public function import()
{
    // get all the files
    $files = File::files('../import');


    foreach ($files as $file) {
        // load text file contents
        $contents = file_get_contents($file);
        echo $contents; // as expected
        $contents .= 'a longer test' . $contents;
        echo $contents; // weird stuff

// test txt file contents inline
$contents2 = <<<EOD
SOCIETE  JERSIAISE
POUR  L ’É T U DE  DE  L ’H IST O IR E  ET  DE  LA  LANGUE  DU  PAYS,
LA  CONSERVATION  DES  A N TIQ U ITÉS  DE  L ’IL E ,  ET  LA  PUBLICATION
DE  DOCUMENTS  HISTORIQUES,  ETC.,  ETC.
FONDÉE  LE  28  JANVIER,  1873.
DIXIÈME  BULLETIN  ANNUEL.
:
C.  LE   F E U VRE,  IM PR IM E U R -É D IT EU R   D E  LA  SOCIÉTÉ,
BERESFORD  LIBRARY ,  ST. -H ÉLIE R .
1885.

 = Page 1 =


EOD;


        echo $contents2; // works
        $contents2 .= 'a longer test' . $contents2;
        echo $contents2; // prints as expected

    }
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.concat.php You're not doing concatenation. You're doing mathematical addition.

Comment: Been writing too much JavaScript! :)  Still doesn't work though

Comment: and now a stealth edit...

Comment: @MarcB, that's because it wasn't the problem, only wrote this for Stackoverflow to simplify the code :)

Comment: well, I can't see how prepending a string to another string would make the whole thing get zeroed out. what exactly is in this text? even if it started with a null char or something, you should have at LEAST `test` in your output, since that'd come before any other text there.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. Output: "hello world!!!hello world!!!testhello world!!!" Make sure the file you're trying to access has content and is readable; most likely that and/or a path issue. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Show us how you're getting `$file`.

Comment: @MarcB, added better examples - long day so writing badly, sorry

Comment: well, if it's a display issue, then `echo strlen($contents)` before/after the concatenation should change by only the length of whatever you're actually concatting in there. If you echo a non-zero length but the actual text doesn't display at all, then it's obviously a display problem and nothing something wrong with php itself.

Comment: I've tried both your methods, minus the Laravel stuff and got output, so I for one do not know what is causing the non-printing.

Comment: It could also be an encoding issue. One file may be encoded as UTF-8 while the other is ANSI.

Comment: Printing another string to the page removes the Chinese text, but lots of question marks in diamonds appear throughout the text. This makes the string almost print correctly. I can then run my regex and it matches anything I added the the string 'a longer test', but never anything from the file. I'm going to try resaving it with different software.

Comment: It's a character encoding issue then; next to 100% sure. If you haven't an code editor to save as different formats, look up Notepad++ it's free and a not bad at all; it's what I use.

Comment: *"**FIXED!**

File encoding is UTF-16LE, changed to UTF-8 in PhpStorm and it behaves."* - Knew it ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii-  thanks to you and MarcB

Comment: You're welcome Richard, glad to know it's been resolved, *cheers*

Comment: You know that Stack lets you put in your own answer and mark it as solved, just so the question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED!

File encoding is UTF-16LE, changed to UTF-8 in PhpStorm and it behaves.

Or in code:

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
        // load text file contents
        $contents = file_get_contents($file);

        // fix encoding
        $contents = mb_convert_encoding($contents, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16');
        echo $contents;
        .....
```

Comment: Right on Richard +1 tell it to "behave" ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$data_to_write = 'test';
$file_handle = fopen($file, 'a'); 
fwrite($file_handle, $data_to_write);
fclose($file_handle);
```

Comment: I don't think you understand the issue.

Comment: that appends the text, OP wants to pre-pend.

Comment: I don't want to edit the file - just get it's contents and work with it